# unable to get virtual hosts on apache to work

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm really struggling with configuring virtual hosts for an apache server in windows 7.

I've read as many posts as I can and I think I've done everything right but I cant get my browser to go to anything - it states (in chrome) webpage unavailable and in firefox says server not found.

In my hosts file I have set up:

```
127.0.0.1       ebdowns
127.0.0.1       loc
127.0.0.1       ebdowns.loc
```

In httpd.conf I have included the vhosts file and added these entries to the vhost.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\ebdowns"
 ServerName ebdowns.loc
</VirtualHost>
```

The server appears to start but http:// ebdowns.loc or http:// localhost - or anything dont work.

Where have I gone wrong?

I incorrectly posted this in serverfault so I hope this is the right place as I don't understand what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using XAMPP or MAMP?

Comment: Hi. i'm using wamp. I was thinking of stripping it all out and starting again

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying ServerName localhost
then in your etc/hosts file define 127.0.0.1 localhost   aswell..

share the logs...